# Moodle plugin display different secret values for google-oauth plugin

Tags: php, google-oauth, browser-cache, moodle, aws-opsworks

I have a `moodle` installation on `AWS OpsWorks` (5 instances) for a third party client who develops `moodle`.  I don't have enough moodle or php knowledge to go upon.

The issue is caching I think.  We deploy to the `OpsWorks` instances via a `CodeDeploy` agent that uses a `.tar.gz` from an `S3` bucket, so I know all instances are synced code wise.

When I enter the secret into the [oauth-plugin](https://github.com/mouneyrac/moodle-auth_googleoauth2) on Chrome, save it and open the same page on FireFox, I see the old secret value and not the one I just entered.

There's an `ElastiCache` layer as well as an `RDS` layer for the DB, and also a `local-cache` value in `config.php`.

My question is whether anyone has come up against anything like this, and if not, then how to begin trouble shooting?